# Chrome Table Division Handling different than IE

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, html-table, format

I am new to  CSS. When I run the following code in IE it lines up the spans as expected, fixing there widths to 100px and padding the sides with as much space as necessary depending on the window size.

```
<table ID="tblRecordCount" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td />
        <td style="width:100px">
            <span ID="lbl1" runat="server">Records1</span>
        </td>
        <td style="width:100px">
            <span ID="lbl2" runat="server">Records2</span>
        </td>
        <td style="width:100px">
            <span ID="lbl3" runat="server">Records3</span>
        </td>
        <td />
    </tr>
</table>
```

When you run it in Chrome the browser either sets the first td width to 0px and fills in the last one, or sets the first and last to 0 and stretches the middle ones to fill the space.

Any CSS tricks to tell Chrome to behave? You can see this behavior in jsFiddle.

Comment: What is `<td />` in your markup? table data cell is an container element not empty one.

Comment: td is the equivalent of an ASP:TableCell? I want it to be empty so that the 3 spans in the middle center the screen.

Comment: By the way FireFox renders it the same as IE.